# How do I Start a job of a function i just defined?

Tags: powershell, jobs

How do I Start a job of a function i just defined?

```
function FOO { write-host "HEY" }

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { FOO } |
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Result:

```
Receive-Job: The term 'FOO' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet,
function ,script file or operable program.
```

What do I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As @Shay points out, `FOO` needs to be defined for the job. Another way to do this is to use the `-InitializationScript` parameter to prepare the session.

For your example:

```
$functions = {
    function FOO { write-host "HEY" }
}

Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock {FOO}|
    Wait-Job| Receive-Job
```

This can be useful if you want to use the same functions for different jobs.

Comment: This is good, but how can I use the same functions in the main script?

Comment: @BenPower See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

@Rynant's suggestion of `InitializationScript` is great

I thought the purpose of (script) blocks is so that you can pass them around. So depending on how you are doing it, I would say go for:

```
$FOO = {write-host "HEY"}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $FOO | wait-job |Receive-Job
```

Of course you can parameterize script blocks as well:

```
$foo = {param($bar) write-host $bar}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $foo -ArgumentList "HEY" | wait-job | receive-job
```

Comment: I agree that if all @Alex58 wants to do is run a single function a parameterized ScriptBlock is the way to go. But if he is defining multiple functions or an advanced function, `InitializationScript` can be very helpful. For example: you could define functions `FOO` and `BAR` in the initialization script, then run a job with scriptblock `{FOO; BAR}` and another job with `{BAR; FOO}`

Comment: @Rynant - I agree. That is why I said "depending on how you are doing it". PS: Got the name wrong in my answer. Meant Rynant and not Matt.

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me as:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${Function:FOO}
```

Comment: This worked for me with also adding `-ArgumentList`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this answer is way better then the marked one

Comment: This is great, but it should be noted that this only works if the function in question doesn't call _another_ function in the global scope. As far as I can tell this amounts to using the named `${Function:FOO}`'s contents as the script block, no more no less. This is **really** just the same as the accepted answer, with the one difference that it reuses an existing function definition instead of assigning and then using a (script) block.

Answer (score 5):

An improvement to @Rynant's answer:

You can define the function as normal in the main body of your script:

```
Function FOO 
{ 
  Write-Host "HEY" 
}
```

and then recycle this definition within a scriptblock:

```
$export_functions = [scriptblock]::Create(@"
  Function Foo { $function:FOO }
"@)
```

(makes more sense if you have a substantial function body) and then pass them to `Start-Job` as above:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {FOO} -InitializationScript $export_functions| Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

I like this way, as it is easier to debug jobs by running them locally under the debugger.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work, the job just outputs "$function:FOO" instead of "HEY"

Comment: I've updated it with a version that definitely works. Funny, sure it was working before but can confirm the old version wasn't

Comment: How do you pass parameters using this syntax?

Comment: Add a `Param` block to the FOO definition and then `-ArgumentList $args` to the `Start-Job` invocation

Comment: Does this technique work with exporting 3 functions, and some code outside a function (which you would call from Start-Job, and that code would then call the functions)?   That's my scenario and trying to figure out how variables get passed to the code outside the function (but inside the -ScriptBlock )

Comment: Please post a separate question for this - it's not clear from such a short description. Might be easier to dot-source the file

Comment: I really wish that someone had answered @DougN 's comment here.  It was very clear what he was asking for; it's exactly what I wanted to know.  I have no idea where to find his question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I see you have posted your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879051/reuse-2-functions-in-start-threadjob) and it has been answered

Answer (score 3):

The function needs to be inside the scriptblock:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { function FOO { write-host "HEY" } ; FOO } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Mine is completed, not sure why yours is still running. Can you test this again in a fresh instance?

Comment: I think there's an issue with xp sp3 and posh 2.0. Now I'm on a windows 7 and backgroudjobs work great. I've googled but found nothing. Maybe just my personal issue on xp sp3. Some similar was start-job with import-module with w2k3 or xp sp3... On w2k8 and w2k8r2 no problems.

Answer (score 3):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a systematic summary:

- **PowerShell's [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs)**<sup>[1]</sup> run in an out-of-process runspace (a hidden child process) and therefore **share no state with the caller**.
- Therefore, **`function` definition** created by the caller in-session are *not* visible to background jobs and **must be *recreated* in the context of the job.**<sup>[2]</sup>
- The **simplest way to recreate a function definition** is to combine ***namespace variable notation*** (e.g, `$function:FOO` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375)) with the **[`$using:scope`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables)**, as shown below.

  - Sadly, due to a long-standing **bug**, `$using:` references do *not* work in script blocks passed to [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s (as well as [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)'s)  **`-InitializationScript`** parameter, as of this writing (Windows PowerShell, PowerShell (Core) 7.3.6) - see [GitHub issue #4530](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4530)

A self-contained example:

```
function FOO { "HEY" }

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 

  # Redefine function FOO in the context of this job.
  $function:FOO = "$using:function:FOO" 
  
  # Now FOO can be invoked.
  FOO

} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above outputs string `HEY`, as intended.

Note:

- *Assigning to* `$function:FOO` implicitly creates function `FOO` (on demand) and makes the assigned value the function's *body*; the assigned value may either be a [`[scriptblock]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) instance or a `[string]`, i.e. source-code *text*.
- *Referencing* `$function:FOO` retrieves a preexisting `FOO` function's body as a `[scriptblock]` instance. Prepending the `$using:` scope (`$using:function:FOO`) retrieves the the body of the `FOO` function from the *caller's* scope.
- Note:

  - Due to `$using:`, `$using:function:FOO` is *not* a `[scriptblock]` instance, but a `[string]` in the case of `Start-Job`, due to the - surprising - manner in which `[scriptblock]` instance are *deserialized* when undergoing cross-process serialization; the behavior was declared to be by design - see [GitHub issue #11698](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11698) for a discussion.
  - As such, the `"..."` around `$using:function:FOO` are redundant for `Start-Job`, but not for `Start-ThreadJob`, where serialization is *not* involved, and recreating the body *from a string* is necessary to avoid state corruption (see [GitHub issue #16461](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16461#issuecomment-967759037) for details).

    - The fact that `Start-ThreadJob` allows `$using:function:FOO` references at all is probably an *oversight*, given that they have been explicitly disallowed in script blocks used with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` (PowerShell v7+) - see [GitHub issue #12378](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12378#issuecomment-616650654).
    - Therefore, with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` a helper variable that stringifies the function body on the caller's side first is required - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273544/45375).

---

<sup>[1] This answer doesn't just apply to the child-process-based jobs created by [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job), but analogously also to the generally preferable *thread*-based jobs created with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) and the thread-based parallelism available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)  `-Parallel`, as well as to PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) - in short: it applies to any scenario in which PowerShell executes out-of-runspace (in a different runspace).</sup>

<sup>[2] The alternative is to provide such definitions via *script files* (`*.ps1`) or *modules* that the job would have to [dot-source (`.` )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) or import.</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to define the function name inside the Scriptblock with a variable?

Comment: @secondplace: Yes: `function Foo { 'foo!' }; Start-Job { $funcName = 'Foo'; $null = New-Item Function:$funcName -Value "$using:function:Foo"; Foo } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`. Note that you can always invoke a script block (stored in a variable) directly: `$sb = { 'foo!' }; & $sb`

Comment: The `$using:function:Foo` itself cannot be concatenated with `$funcName`?
Currently I hardcode the available functions using another example you posted `${function:Foo} = ${using:function:Foo}` and then call the one I need via `& $funcName`.
Using your `${...}` example I found to be more versatile since it allows for `-` and numbers in the function name.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the function passed to the InitializationScript param on Start-Job isn't large Rynant's answer will work, but if the function is large you may run into the below error.

> [localhost] There is an error launching the background process. Error
> reported: The filename or extension is too long"

Capturing the function's definition and then using Invoke-Expression on it in the ScriptBlock is a better alternative.

```
function Get-Foo {
    param
    (
        [string]$output
    )

    Write-Output $output
}

$getFooFunc = $(Get-Command Get-Foo).Definition

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression "function Get-Foo {$using:getFooFunc}"
    Get-Foo -output "bar"
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job

PS C:\Users\rohopkin> Get-Job | Receive-Job
bar
```

Comment: How would this look if the function had named arguments?

Comment: @DHummel, I updated my example to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take.  A function is just a scriptblock assigned to a variable.  Oh, it has to be a threadjob.  It can't be foreach-object -parallel.

```
$func = { 'hi' } # or
function hi { 'hi' }; $func = $function:hi

start-threadjob { & $using:func } | receive-job -auto -wait

hi
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ben Power's comment under the accepted answer was my concern also, so I googled how to get function definitions, and I found `Get-Command` - though this gets only the function body. But it can be used also if the function is coming from elsewhere, like a dot-sourced file. So I came up with the following (hold my naming convention :)), the idea is to re-build the function definitions delimited by newlines:

```
Filter Greeting {param ([string]$Greeting) return $Greeting}
Filter FullName {param ([string]$FirstName, [string]$LastName) return $FirstName + " " + $LastName}
$ScriptText = ""
$ScriptText += "Filter Greeting {" + (Get-Command Greeting).Definition + "}`n"
$ScriptText += "Filter FullName {" + (Get-Command FullName).Definition + "}`n"
$Job = Start-Job `
            -InitializationScript $([ScriptBlock]::Create($ScriptText)) `
            -ScriptBlock {(Greeting -Greeting "Hello") + " " + (FullName -FirstName "PowerShell" -LastName "Programmer")}
$Result = $Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
$Result
$Job | Remove-Job
```