# How do I call Start-Job which depends on a function in the same powershell module as the function calling Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, jobs, powershell-2.0, powershell-jobs

I'm writing some powershell to talk to the AWS API, in a single module.  I have written one function, `Get-CloudFormation`, which returns the status of a CloudFormation.  I've written another function, `Delete-CloudFormation`, which after firing off a delete-CF API request, *tries* to start a job which polls the status of the CloudFormation using my `Get-CloudFormation`.

I call `Export-ModuleMember` on `Get-CloudFormation` (but not `Delete-CloudFormation`; that's a private function).  `Get-CloudFormation` is defined earlier in the module-file than `Delete-CloudFormation`.

My `Start-Job` call (inside `Delete-CloudFormation`) looks like:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name "CloudFormationWaitForDeleteSuccess" -ScriptBlock {
    $status = ""
    $time = 0
    while($status -ne "DELETE_COMPLETE") {
        Write-Verbose ("Checking CloudFormation status")
        $stack = Get-CloudFormation -accessKey $accessKey -secretKey $secretKey -stackName $stackName
        $status = $stack.Status
        Start-Sleep -seconds 10
        $time += 10
    }
    Write-Host "CloudFormation delete-complete after $time seconds $stackName"
}
```

When `Delete-CloudFormation` runs, I get an exception:

```
The term 'Get-CloudFormation' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CloudFormation:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why?  And how do I fix it?

I found [7152090](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162090/how-do-i-start-a-job-of-a-function-i-just-defined) which I think is similar, but calling `Start-Job` with `-InitializationScript { Get-CloudFormation }` gives roughly the same error.

If I call Start-Job with `-InitializationScript { Import-Module ".\awsutils.psm1" }` then `.` is my profile's documents directory.  Even if I bind a variable to `Get-Location` outside the `Start-Job` and call it like `-InitializationScript { Import-Module "$location\awsutils.psm1" }`.

Answer (score 9):

move you module `awsutils.psm1` in the canonical path for powershell modules:

```
$env:userprofile\documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\awsutils"
```

then initialize start-job like this

```
-InitializationScript { Import-Module awsutils }
```

Tested with my custom modules and start-job works.

try also, if you don't want move your psm1 this:

```
-InizializationScript { import-module -name c:\yourpath\yourmodulefolder\ }
```

where `yourmoduleforder` contain only one psm1 file.

Comment: I guess if the OP wanted to be more dynamic the main script could copy the module into the C:\Windows...\Powershell modules directory so it could just use Import-Module without a full path. It could be removed later... hehe

Answer (score 3):

Background jobs are autonomous things. They aren't a separate thread sharing resources, they are actually run in a whole new PowerShell.exe process. So I think you will need to use `Import-Module` inside your script block to have you module members available there.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was setting `$env:WhereAmI = Get-Location` before the call to `Start-Job`, and then changing to `-InitializationScript { Import-Module "$env:WhereAmI\awsutils.psm1 }`.  After the `Start-Job` call, I called `Remove-Item env:\WhereAmI` to clean-up.

(I wanted a solution that didn't require me to be developing the module within the $PSModulePath, because then source-control is a little more painful to set up.)

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
$root = $PSScriptRoot

$initScript = [scriptblock]::Create("Import-Module -Name '$root\Modules\Publish-Assigned_CB_Reports.psm1'")

$job1 = Start-Job -InitializationScript $initScript -ScriptBlock {} -ArgumentList
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: this is the answer I sought, and I think for anyone knowledgeable enough to attempt running background jobs will see the answer as self-explanatory