# Basic multithreaded Consumers algorithm in PowerShell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, producer-consumer

I want create a queue of ffmpeg commands and then let N threads consume the queue launching an instance of ffmpeg with parameters:

here some code:

```
#looping on $items to prepare the params
foreach($input in $items){
    {...}

    #adding a param in queue
    $global:jobsQueue.Enqueue($ffmpegParam)
} 

#block code to be executed in different thread
$block = {
    Param($queue, $ffmpegDir)
    while($true){
        if($queue.TryDequeue($params)){
            $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo($ffmpegDir, $params)
            $pinfoMap.$input.UseShellExecute = $false
            $pinfoMap.$input.CreateNoWindow = $true
            $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
            $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
            $p.Start()
            $p.WaitForExit()
        } else {break}
    }
}

#miserably failing to start the previous block code
for($i = 0; $i -lt 1; $i++){
    Start-Job -Name "process $i" -ScriptBlock $block -ArgumentList $global:jobsQueue,$ffmpegDir
}
```

A job is actually started but it does nothing and i don't get why. I read those pages but i wasn't able to come up with a solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1

[How do I Start a job of a function i just defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162090/how-do-i-start-a-job-of-a-function-i-just-defined)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/b68c1c68-e0f0-47b7-ba9f-749d06621a2c/calling-a-function-using-startjob

Comment: You never define `$params` in your script block.

Comment: Also, never use `$input` as a variable name.  What you're getting there are null values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)  Can you please elaborate? I'm fairly new to PowerShell and it's a mess coming from Java ^^" Happy Christmas eve as well!

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable. Intended for pipeline values. Look at the help topic

Comment: i changed the variable name but still not working

Comment: Because you never addressed the first comment.  Your logic is wrong

Comment: If i am not mistaken, [`ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx) fill `$params` if there is something in queue and returns `$true`, otherwise returns `$false`. I know that there is something wrong in what i wrote, that's why i'm here ^^". Can you please elaborate a better solution?