# Powershell: calling one function from another and second function triggers a backgroud run

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do something similar to this.
First function
Second function calls first function and trigger a Start-Job

example:

```
Function CreateDeleteDirs {
Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $True,
  HelpMessage = 'Remote Path to create dirs on. Provide full path.')
  ]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$RootPath
  )
  ***do some stuffs***
}
Function CreateDeleteDirBack {
Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $True,
  HelpMessage = 'Remote Path to create dirs on. Provide full path.')
  ]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$RootPath
  )
  $scriptBlock = {
 param ($RootPath)
 CreateDeleteDirs -RootPath $RootPath
```

}
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($RootPath)
    }
}

So its always failing with calling CreateDeleteDirs from second function .. how can I do this

The exact error snippet

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> CreateDeleteDirsBackground -RootPath Y: 

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
21     Job21           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      



PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> Receive-Job Job21
The term 'CreateDeleteDirs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CreateDeleteDirs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost


PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules>
```

Comment: I would like to run the above function CreateDeleteDirs in background (till external kill) . calling function CreateDeleteDirs in standalone works fine

Comment: `CreateDeleteDirs`  vs. `CreateDeleteDir` ;)

Comment: Sorry my bad in type here the names are same  "CreateDeleteDirs"

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162090/how-do-i-start-a-job-of-a-function-i-just-defined

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to output the root path so we can see it working and waited for the job to complete.

```
$script_block = {
  function CreateDeleteDirs {
    Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage = 'Remote Path to create dirs on. Provide full path.')]
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      [string]$RootPath
    )

    write-host "Rootpath = '$RootPath'"
  }

  function CreateDeleteDirBack  {
    Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage = 'Remote Path to create dirs on. Provide full path.')]
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      [string]$RootPath
    )

    CreateDeleteDirs -RootPath $RootPath 
  } 
}

Start-Job -InitializationScript $script_block -ScriptBlock {CreateDeleteDirBack  'foo'} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I couldnt use CreateDeleteDirs as an individual function further with this structure