# Start-Job Error: The term <NAME> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: multithreading, powershell, start-job

I have the following functions (these are simplified examples)

```
function a {return 2}
function b {$a=a; return $a+2}
function c {$a=a; return $a*10}
```

When I run the following codes

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Function:b -Name "test"

Receive-Job -Name "test"
```

It shows me this error:

> The term 'a' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any idea on how to start a function as a job while that function calls another function? Each function needs to be used independently as well (explained in Edit 1). In short, I need to be able to run function `c` (as a job) too.

**Edit 1:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162842/4741225) provides a solution but if I do so, I can not run functions independently. It is almost the [same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839512/4741225) provided by @TheIncorrigible1.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a `scriptblock` to `Start-Job`, it's no longer part of your scope; it cannot see the external definitions.  You would need to nest it inside your function to be applicable:

```
function b {
    function a { return 2 }

    $a = a
    return $a + 2
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Function:b -Name test
Receive-Job -Name test
```

Comment: +1. I have seen almost the same approach but what if I want to use `function a` in another part of the script. It is my issue because I have some functions that I use frequently such as `Logger` or `Validation` that I use in many functions.

Comment: @Alin The problem is `Start-Job` starts up a new session so nothing is available without it explicitly being so.  You could change your function to take arguments that are functions to invoke and pass them through using `Start-Job` with `ArgumentList`.  Alternatively, you use the `FilePath` parameterset.

Comment: I see. Is there any way that I be able to run `function a` separately. I mean is it possible to have a scriptblock of different functions as it is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162842/4741225) and run just one of the functions?

Comment: @Alin Yes, you can also use the `InitializationScript` parameter.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a JOB system for powershell that isn't insane and stupid and useless by default?