# How can i make foreach loop runing in powershell even a function is called and not yet completed inside it.?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a function call inside foreach loop, i do not want to wait till that function gets completed and need to make my foreach loop running, so i can achieve multi-threading concept in powershell.
Is this possible?
Please guide thanks.

```
foreach ($folders in $txtfilepath)

ftp_upload1 $foldertemp $Freelancername $articleid $Freelancermailfinal
```

As this is a upload function and wait time is more sometimes so i need to work as multi-thread so it will make all upload requests asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally i got answer.

```
$FOO = {write-host "HEY"}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $FOO | wait-job |Receive-Job
```

parameterize script blocks

```
$foo = {param($bar) write-host $bar}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $foo -ArgumentList "HEY" | wait-job | receive-job
```

No doubt that i copied from some other post and here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162090/how-do-i-start-a-job-of-a-function-i-just-defined)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using PowerShell **background jobs**. It works like:

```
foreach ($folders in $txtfilepath) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
       ftp_upload1 $foldertemp $Freelancername $articleid $Freelancermailfinal
    }
}
```

But you probably want to receive the result etc. so take a look at [about_jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thank you @Martin, but after adding background job function is not calling, its just skipping the function, please correct me if im missing something, i have same code whatever you hav provided.

Comment: You probably have to add the parameters as input to the script block. Just go and read the about_jobs document.

Comment: ok martin its working after providing some parameters, but again its calling function but not running foreach simultaneously, its waiting till function gets completes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to considering using **ForEach-Object -Parallel** switch:

Windows PowerShell 5.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

OR

PowerShell Core 7.0 Preview 5
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-7