# Powershell implement Switch Statement

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, switch-statement, scriptblock, foreach-object

I would like to implement a
-parallel
Switch to one of my skripts

Non Parallel Version:

```
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object {
          #region ... local Variables
          $stepWidthLocal = $stepWidth
<#
my code
#>
```

Parallel Funktion:

```
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit ($parallelBlocks * 10) -Parallel {
          #region ... local Variables
          $stepWidthLocal = $using:stepWidth
<#
my code
#>
```

What I dont want is:

```
$myParallel = $true
if ($myParallel) {
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit ($parallelBlocks * 10) -Parallel {
    #region ... local Variables
    $stepWidthLocal = $using:stepWidth
    <#
    my code
    #>
  } #end $tmpArray | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit ($parallelBlocks * 10) -Parallel
} #end if($myParallel) 
else {
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object {
    #region ... local Variables
    $stepWidthLocal = $stepWidth
    <#
my code
#>
  } #end $tmpArray | ForEach-Object {
} #end else {
```

I want something like this:

```
$myCode = <#
define my Codeblock
#>
$myParallel = $true
if ($myParallel) {
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit ($parallelBlocks * 10) -Parallel {
    #region ... local Variables
    $stepWidthLocal = $using:stepWidth
    $myCode
  } #end $tmpArray | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit ($parallelBlocks * 10) -Parallel
} #end if($myParallel) 
else {
  $tmpArray | ForEach-Object {
    #region ... local Variables
    $stepWidthLocal = $stepWidth
    $myCode
  } #end $tmpArray | ForEach-Object {
} #end else {
```

Now I want to create some kind of switch statement without duplicating the entire code (block <# my code#>).

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the reusable code as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), but note that you won't be able to use it *directly* in your [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel` script block and instead have to *recreate it* there, via its *string* representation passed to the static [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) method; using a simplified example:

```sh
# Your reusable code block.
# Note the .ToString() call to obtain its string representation.
$myCodeSource = {
  "hi from thread $([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
}.ToString()


1, 2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
  # ...
  # Note: You can pass arguments, if the script block is prepared to handle them.
  & ([scriptblock]::Create($using:myCodeSource)) 
}
```

<sup>Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273544/45375) contains an analogous solution for using a *function* from the caller's scope in a `ForEach-Object -Parallel` script block.</sup>

The above output something like the following:

```
hi from thread 35
hi from thread 36
```

Note (as of PowerShell 7.2):

- `ForEach-Object -Parallel` actively *prevents* direct use of script blocks from the caller's scope (accessed via the `$using:`) scope, because using script blocks across threads can lead to thread-safety issues; curiously, however, the related [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) *does* accept script blocks via `$using:` - though that may have been an oversight.

  - *Recreating* a script block via its *string* representation, as shown above, works around this limitation.
- [GitHub issue #12378](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12378) discusses this behavior, including a possible enhancement to let `ForEach-Object` itself automatically recreate the script block in a thread-safe manner.

  - More generally, [GitHub issue #12240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240) proposes an opt-in mechanism that would allow copying the caller's definitions to each thread, making `$using:` references unnecessary.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user3898488; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arguments = @{ }
if ($myParallel) {
    $arguments = @{ parallel = $true; $throttlelimit = 10 }
}
$tmpArray | ForEach-Object @arguments {
...
}
```

Comment: I tested this solution but I failed as I cannot pass the variables to the block. You need to pass the variables with $using: to the parallelblock: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/ which doesnt work in the nonparellel block. So you could implement a $useParallel switch but as you cannot pass the $useParallel itself, this doesnt work either. So for all I know, the idea is great, but it doesnt work