# PowerShell Use UDF in ForEach-Object -Parallel

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have some dificulties with using an User Define Function inside the ForEach-Object when the Parallel is active:

```
function Add([Int]$number) {
    Write-Output "Run for $number"
}

1..4 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Add -number $_
}
```

I get an error message:

> The term 'Add' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I believe it is a common proactivity use an UDF inside *foreach* loop. Do you have any workaround for that? The $using: is applicable only for variable, not function, right?

Comment: As for `$using:` only working with variables: indeed, although you can - in principle - use _namespace variable notation_ to get a function's _body_, as a _script block_: `$using:function:Add`. However, while that works with `Start-Job` and `Start-ThreadJob`, it is explicitly prevent with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` (and, based on the rationale for that, should probably be prevented in `Start-ThreadJob` too). See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 3):

You could either define the function in the scope of the *parallel block* (Runsapce):

```
1..4 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    function Add([Int]$number) {
        Write-Output "Run for $number"
    }
    
    Add -number $_
}
```

Or store the definition of your function and then pass it to the scope of your *parallel block* and [dot source it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
function Add([Int]$number) {
    Write-Output "Run for $number"
}

$def = "function Add { ${function:Add} }"

1..4 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    . ([scriptblock]::Create($using:def))
    Add -number $_
}
```

Linked [helpful answer from mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273189/how-to-pass-a-custom-function-inside-a-foreach-object-parallel) shows a much more cleaner alternative to define the function in the parallel scope. *Definitely recommend this method, easier to read and understand*:

```
function Add([Int]$number) {
    Write-Output "Run for $number"
}

$def = ${function:Add}.ToString()

1..4 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $function:Add = $using:Def
    Add -number $_
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 actually a lot cleaner the approach on the linked answer, wasn't aware of it. Thanks

Comment:  Including the function definition directly in the `-Parallel` script block is a pragmatic solution, though not always a (clean) option.

Comment: I have always used this method and always wondered if there was something cleaner, guess I learnt something new today, as per usual with your answers :P @mklement0