# Foreach-Object -Parallel returning "The term 'write-host' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program"

Tags: powershell

I've encountered this issue in a longer script and have simplified here to show the minimal code required to reproduce it (I think). It outputs numbers followed by letters:
1 a
1 b
1 c...
2 a
2 b
2 c...
all the way to "500 z"

```
Function Write-HelloWorld
{
    Param($number)
    write-host -Object $number
}

$numbers = 1..500
$letters = "a".."z"
$Function = get-command Write-HelloWorld 
$numbers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    ${function:Write-HelloWorld} = $using:Function
    foreach($letter in $using:letters) {
        Write-HelloWorld -number "$_ $letter"
    }
}
```

I'm seeing 2 types of sporadically (not every time I run it):

1. "The term 'write-host' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program." As understand it, write-host should always be available. Adding the line "Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility" just before the call to write-host didn't help
2. Odd output like the below, specifically all the "write-host :" lines.

[image]

Comment: Does this solve the problem? `$Function = (Get-Command Write-HelloWorld).Definition`

Comment: Whoo! Yes! Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon. Could you share why?

Comment: Not sure why but a clear indication is that you're attempting to pass and re-use a reference object with increased complexity for your function definition rather than a simple string (the `.Definition` property value)

Comment: Needles to say, even if my above comment was not the actual cause of your issue, there is no need to pass in a `FunctionInfo` instance to your runspaces when the same can be accomplished and clearly without failures with a simple string definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74258063/45375) ***demonstrates the problem* with your approach well** and links to a GitHub issue explaining the underlying problem (runspace affinity); however, that demonstration isn't the right *solution* (it wasn't meant to be), as it uses *explicit synchronization* to allow only *one* thread at a time to call the function, which negates the benefits of parallelism.

**As for a *solution*:**

**You must pass a *string* representation of your `Write-HelloWorld`'s function body to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel` call**:

```
Function Write-HelloWorld
{
    Param($number)
    write-host -Object $number
}

$numbers = 1..500
$letters = "a".."z"
# Get the body of the Write-HelloWorld function *as a string*
# Alternative, as suggested by @Santiago:
#   $funcDefString = (Get-Command -Type Function Write-HelloWorld).Definition
$funcDefString = ${function:Write-HelloWorld}.ToString()
$numbers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  # Redefine the Write-HelloWorld function in this thread,
  # using the *string* representation of its body.
  ${function:Write-HelloWorld} = $using:funcDefString
    foreach($letter in $using:letters) {
        Write-HelloWorld -number "$_ $letter"
    }
}
```

<sup>`${function:Write-HelloWorld}` is an instance of [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375), which allows you to both *get* a function (its *body* as a `[scriptblock]` instance) and to *set* (define) it, by assigning either a `[scriptblock]` or a string containing the function body.</sup>

**By passing a *string*, the function is *recreated in the context of each thread*, which avoids cross-thread issues** that can arise when you pass a [`[System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo) instance, as output by [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command), which **contains a [`[scriptblock]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock) that is bound to the runspace in which it was defined** (i.e., the caller's; that script block is said to have **affinity with the caller's runspace**), and **calling this bound `[scriptblock]` instance from *other* threads (runspaces) isn't safe**.

By contrast, by redefining the function *in each thread*, via a *string*, a thread-specific `[scriptblock]` instance bound to that thread is created, which can safely be called.

In fact, you appear to have found a loophole, given that when you attempt to use a `[scriptblock]` instance *directly* with the `$using:` scope, the command by design breaks with an explicit error message:

```
A ForEach-Object -Parallel using variable cannot be a script block. 
Passed-in script block variables are not supported with ForEach-Object -Parallel,  
and can result in undefined behavior
```

In other words: **PowerShell shouldn't even let you do what you attempted to do**, but unfortunately does, as of PowerShell Core 7.2.7, resulting in the obscure failures you saw  - see [GitHub issue #16461](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16461).

---

**Potential future improvement:**

- An enhancement is being discussed in [GitHub issue #12240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240) to **support copying the caller's state to the parallel threads *on demand***, which would automatically make the caller's functions available, without the need for manual redefinition.

Answer (score 2):

**Note, this answer is meant to prove a point but does not provide the correct solution to the problem**.

See [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74258050/15339544) for the proper way to solve this by simply passing the function's definition as **string** to the runspaces. See also [GitHub Issue #4003](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4003) for more details.

---

It's a very bad idea to pass in a reference object and use it without thread safety, here is proof that by simply adding thread safety to your code the problem is solved:

```
function Write-HelloWorld {
    param($number)
    Write-Host -Object $number
}

$numbers  = 1..500
$letters  = "a".."z"
$Function = Get-Command Write-HelloWorld

$numbers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $refObj = $using:Function

    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($refObj)

    ${function:Write-HelloWorld} = $using:Function
    foreach($letter in $using:letters) {
        Write-HelloWorld -number "$_ $letter"
    }

    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($refObj)
}
```

To be precise, this issue is related to **Runspace Affinity**, all [Runspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) are trying to send the invocation back to the origin Runspace thread hence poor PowerShell collapses.