# Reuse 2 functions in Start-ThreadJob

Tags: powershell, start-job

Assuming `Get-Foo` and `Get-Foo2` and `Deploy-Jobs` are 3 functions that are part of a very large module.  I would like to use `Get-Foo` and `Get-Foo2` in `Deploy-Jobs`'s `Start-ThreadJob` (below) *without* reloading the entire module each time.

Is an working example available for how to do this?

```Posh
function Deploy-Jobs {

    foreach ($Device in $Devices) {

        Start-ThreadJob -Name $Device -ThrottleLimit 50 -InitializationScript $initScript -ScriptBlock {
            param($Device)

            Get-Foo | Get-Foo2 -List
        
        } -ArgumentList $Device | out-null
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully the linked duplicate explains what you need to do to overcome this.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I can't figure out how to use function with normal PS Verb-Noun functions that use hyphens instead of using `CustomFunction`

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to open another question to ask how to do this.  I really would like to know.

Comment: You can use curly braces, like this: `${function:Verb-Noun}`

Comment: I added another link to duplicates that shows this, give that one a look and let me know if you're able to follow it (the last example from the answer is the one that you need to follow)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply.  Just one more question.... Im still not sure how to get `${function:Verb-Noun} = $using:funcDef`  within `Start-ThreadJob`.   I would really appreciate an example.  All the examples use `ForEach-Object -Parallel`; which I can't use and not familiar with.

Comment: You can also follow the example from the other linked duplicated that shows how you can pass 2 functions at once

Comment: I'd really appreciate an example using `Start-ThreadJob` to do this.   I'm not sure if I need to use `-InitializationScript` or what I need to do in order to get the function within `Start-ThreadJob`.  I don't have any experience with `ForEach-Object -Parallel`; and, can't use it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you can use to pass the function's definition to a different scope is the same for `Invoke-Command` (when PSRemoting), `Start-Job`, `Start-ThreadJob` and `ForeEach-Object -Parallel`. Since you want to invoke 2 different functions in your job's *script block*, I don't think `-InitializationScript` is an option, and even if it is, it might make the code even more complicated than it should be.

You can use this as an example of how you can store 2 function definitions in an array (`$def`), which is then passed to the scope of each TreadJob, this array is then used to define each function in said scope to be later used by each Job.

```
function Say-Hello {
    "Hello world!"
}

function From-ThreadJob {
    param($i)
    "From ThreadJob # $i"
}

$def = @(
    ${function:Say-Hello}.ToString()
    ${function:From-ThreadJob}.ToString()
)

function Run-Jobs {
    param($numerOfJobs, $functionDefinitions)

    $jobs = foreach($i in 1..$numerOfJobs) {
        Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
            # bring the functions definition to this scope
            $helloFunc, $threadJobFunc = $using:functionDefinitions
            # define them in this scope
            ${function:Say-Hello} = $helloFunc
            ${function:From-ThreadJob} = $threadJobFunc
            # sleep random seconds
            Start-Sleep (Get-Random -Maximum 10)
            # combine the output from both functions
            (Say-Hello) + (From-ThreadJob -i $using:i)
        }
    }

    Receive-Job $jobs -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
}

Run-Jobs -numerOfJobs 10 -functionDefinitions $def
```