# powershell: function call inside a function while procesing them paralelly

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I would like to execute 2 powershell functions paralelly
and these functions would call other functions. However, the function calls inside the functions are not to be compiled.
How can I execute the 2 functions paralelly while separating these 2 functions to other subroutines?
Thank you in advance.

```
function funcA {
    write-host "funcA"
}

function funcB {
    write-host "funcB"
    funcA
}
function funcC {
    write-host "funcC"
    funcA
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:funcB}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:funcC}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

It returns with an error:

```
The term 'funcA' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (funcA:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: You will need to pass both functions funcC and funcA or funcB and funcA to the scope of your job. Here is an example of passing two (or more functions) in an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/71887657/15339544

Comment: dersu: did the linked answer help to solve your question?

Comment: Thank you! you helped my a lot. In fact the solution seems to be in my case simply to define a simple script block and us it after -scriptblock

Comment: got it, will close this question as a duplicate then but if you have any further related question please @ me again and we can re-open